# Disable Windows Media Player video autoplay while opening XLSM file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to embed mp4 videos in my XLSM file, and assign the task to some buttons to play the file when needed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\video\" & "video1.mp4"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.Play
End Sub
```

How to stop media files from autoplay when opening the XLSM file?

Comment: I need the code above to play the video in case I need it after clicking the button, but the file is played automatically while opening the XLSM file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Media Player objects have an `autostart` property as part of its `settings` property. You could set this property to false on startup. In the workbook module put the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.WindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = False
End Sub
```

(With the sheet reference adjusted if needed).

Comment: Added this property to the workbook module, but I've seen URL property isn't empty, it contains the path to the video file, so I've added this to your solution  **Sheet1.WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ""**  and it's accepted as a solution.